# get returned fields datatypes from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi, stored-procedures

I've got a small problem I ran into. I want o create a form that ask for a procedure name and returns the params of the stored procedure and the columns that the procedure returns.

For example

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE abc 
    @Param1 int,
    @Param2 varchar(1)
 as
    SELECT * 
    FROM TableA 
    WHERE Param1 = @Param1 and Param2 = @Param2
 GO
```

I know I can get the params of a procedure from SQL Server using this query

```
select  
   'Parameter_name' = name,  
   'Type'   = type_name(user_type_id),  
   'Length'   = max_length,  
   'Prec'   = case when type_name(system_type_id) = 'uniqueidentifier' 
              then precision  
              else OdbcPrec(system_type_id, max_length, precision) end,  
   'Scale'   = OdbcScale(system_type_id, scale),  
   'Param_order'  = parameter_id,  
   'Collation'   = convert(sysname, 
                   case when system_type_id in (35, 99, 167, 175, 231, 239)  
                   then ServerProperty('collation') end)  

  from sys.parameters where object_id = object_id('[dbo].[abc]')
```

and from what I've read on the web, there is no easy way to get the returned datatypes and their names from a stored procedure as the result may be different based on the input params.

I would love to know if there is a way to get the returned datatypes and their names from SQL, but I wouldn't mind if anyone can tell me, or guide me to a place where I can find a solution to get the returned datatypes and their names  from Delphi. Something like when you click on a `TADOStoredProc` and click on AddAllFields option.

Hope I made myself understood.

Thank you

Comment: Would [SET FMTONLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx) be of any use to you?

Comment: This seems to work only for Querys, I've got SP.

Comment: The problem is that there is no data contract with a stored procedure. There is no way the sql engine can determine what datatypes are going to be returned. Consider if your procedure had some conditions inside which could return a different resultset based on the parameters. How would the engine know what would be returned? Simply put, what you are trying to do is not possible.

Comment: @SeanLange One could evaluate all possible paths in the stored procedure and check if they result all in the same recordset. If so, you can determine the schema. "sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set" and "sp_describe_first_result_set" do that. See my answer.

Comment: Of course if you have to evaluate the contents of the procedure wouldn't it just be easier at that point to document the output? This is what the OP seems to be trying to avoid. And of course there is no guarantee the procedure doesn't change between the evaluation and run time.

Comment: @SeanLange The evaluation is automatic and can be made at runtime, anytime, and will show the current state of the store procedure. It's made through the system view or using the stored procedure that I've mentioned in the comment you have just replied. Again, if you want an example of how it's possible, see my answer.

Comment: The point is that just because it once didn't have multiple paths that doesn't mean it will always be that way. If the procedure can only return 1 result your approach works fine. It is however not going to work 100% of the time.

Comment: @SeanLange It can work even when you have multiple paths. However it wont work 100% of the time and it's clearly explained in the documents linked in my answer.

Comment: I understand quite well how it works. My initial comment was made before you posted your answer. I have been agreeing with you that it will not work 100% of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set**.

See the example B *"Returning information about a procedure"*:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO

CREATE PROC Production.TestProc
AS
SELECT Name, ProductID, Color FROM Production.Product ;
SELECT Name, SafetyStockLevel, SellStartDate FROM Production.Product ;
GO

SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set
('Production.TestProc', NULL, 0) ;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878258.aspx#code-snippet-2

It uses the same algorithm as **sp_describe_first_result_set**, so you can find some remarks about this at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx

Comment: Thanks, it works for some particular cases, but I'll stick with this kind of procedures.

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means a complete answer, but I wanted to show how [SET FMTONLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx) is used.  It may solve part of the OP's request.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE abc 
    @Param1 INT
AS
    SELECT TOP(@Param1) *
    FROM master.sys.objects
GO

--When set OFF, 3 rows are returned.
SET FMTONLY OFF
EXEC abc @Param1 = 3

--When set ON, no rows are returned, but the columns and column names of the result set are returned.
SET FMTONLY ON
EXEC abc @Param1 = 3
```

NOTE:  if the stored proc has branching and may return different results sets, this option is not going to work.  Again, this is not a complete answer, just a demo for the OP.

Comment: Should also point out that SET FMTONLY has been replaced in SQL 2012 with more robust features.

Comment: I'll leave this answer up in case the OP is using an "older" version.  If it's SQL 2012 or later, I'd go with @Caffé's answer.

Comment: I know that this won't work for branching, thanks for clearing it up for me!

Comment: @CiucaS This method shown by DMason is used by ADO when checking table schemas and is probably the one used by TADOStoredProc component. You can see how ADO does its spells by analysing the queries it executes (using SQL Server tracing/profile).

Comment: The older SQLOLEDB ADO provider uses  SET FMTONLY. Newer drivers (SQLNCLI11 and the new MSOLEDBSQL) use sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set

Answer (score 0):

It is best not to return many different sets from one stored procedure. If one has to return many sets, it's better to create different procedures and have a uniform data set returned from each of them. Multiple result sets from one procedure is not something that should be returned. Just because something is possible it does not mean it should be made use of.